# How to receive a stack element in a function

Tags: c++, int, stack

I'm currently using stack library on c++ but i don't know how to receive a stack of numbers in a function.. example---->

```
int main
{
    stack <int> pila1;
    juegoEnsayo(pila1);
}

void juegoEnsayo(/*What is supposed to be here???*/ &unaPila)
{
    unaPila.push(6);
    unaPila.push(9);
    unaPila.push(8);
}
```

Comment: Read a good introductory C++ book. You can find a list on StackOverflow

Comment: I tried but i couldn't find anything

Comment: You didn't find *anything* ? [**Here.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list?s=1|32.7215). Found by simply putting `[c++] book` in the search box at the top of this page. And to answer your question, `stack<int>` is what should go there

Answer (score 1):

I suppose `stack <int>` to be there.

```
#include <stack>

using namespace std;

void juegoEnsayo(stack<int> &unaPila)
{
    unaPila.push(6);
    unaPila.push(9);
    unaPila.push(8);
}

int main()
{
    stack <int> pila1;
    juegoEnsayo(pila1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `stack<int>`. So prototype of function will be:
    *`void juegoEnsayo(stack<int>& unaPila);`*

Following is working example. You can find it working [here](http://ideone.com/x2crQO):

```
#include <stack>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void juegoEnsayo(stack<int>& unaPila)
{
    unaPila.push(6);
    unaPila.push(9);
    unaPila.push(8);
}

template<typename T> void printElm(stack<T> mystack)
{
    while (!mystack.empty())
    {
        cout << mystack.top() << " | ";
        mystack.pop();
    }
}

int main()
{
    stack<int> pila1;
    printElm(pila1);
    cout<<endl;
    juegoEnsayo(pila1);
    printElm(pila1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ok, it works fine , i found the problem why by writting stack<int> wasn't working, i had written the function under the main() one and i had put the declaration over "using namespace std;" i'm definetly a noob ,thanks you all